# How to flatten with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have:

```
    businesses: [
    {businessName: 'A', "address":[loc1, loc2, loc3]},
    {businessName: 'B', "address":[loc1, loc2]},
    {businessName: 'C', "address":[loc1]}
};
```

I want to ng-repeat this object with output:

```
A | street, city, zip, state 
A | street, city, zip, state 
A | street, city, zip, state 
B | street, city, zip, state 
B | street, city, zip, state 
C | street, city, zip, state
```

In other words, i want to display this object as flat in a table with ng-repeat.

Do i have to flatten it myself, or does ng-repeat have the power to do this?

Ideally i could just do something like

```
ng-repeat business in businesses
business.businessName | business.address.City | business.address.State
```

By specifying address, it should know i want them all.

Otherwise, how do i flatted an object like this one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Seems like you could process it a bit, something like:

```
var flatBusinesses = [];
for (business in businesses) {
    for (address in business.addresses) {
        flatBusinesses.push ({name: business.name, address: address.City, state: address.State}
    }
}
```

And then just repeat on flatBusinesses in the view

Comment: Thanks, i don't know why i couldn't think of that. I will try tomorrow and accept if it works. Seems like it should.

Answer (score 3):

The underscore library has a number of functions for dealing with javascript arrays and objects that work well as a complement to angular:

http://underscorejs.org/

You would need to download the library and add it to your project.

Then you could write:

```
var flatBusinesses = _.flatten(_.pluck(businesses, 'address'));
```

You should be able to add the underscore library to the scope:

```
$scope._ = _;
```

And then add this directly to your template:

```
<div ng-repeat="business in _.flatten(_.pluck(businesses, 'address'))">
{{business.businessName}} | {{business.address.City}} | {{business.address.State}}
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

So, I didn't read your questions carefully enough, and flatten and pluck aren't going to cut it in your case.

I put together a fiddle playing around with underscore to make it work, but the final result is **not** an improvement over rquinn's response.

Anyways, here is the fiddle if you want to look at it: http://jsfiddle.net/pna7f5h3/