# AngularJS - Display complex JSON data with a single ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, nested, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to display all the books of some series. I used nested ng-repeat and it works well. However, due to some recent changes on layout requirements, I cannot use nested ng-repeat (I want a single list of books). I would expect something like below

```
<ul>
    <li>book1 of series1</li>
    <li>book 2 of series 1</li>
    <li>book1 of series 2</li>
    <li>book2 of series 2</li> 
    <li>book1 of series 3</li>
    <li>book2 of series 3</li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to do it with 1 ng-repeat? Or with other approach? (I.e. Array)

**Data**

```
var data = {
    "records": [
        {
            "name": "Spectrum Series",
            "seriesid": "SpectrumSeries",
            "book": [
                {
                    "name": "White Curse",
                    "bookid": "WhiteCurse",
                    "image": "book1"                    
                },
                {
                    "name": "Blue Fox",
                    "bookid": "BlueFox",
                    "image": "book2"                   
                }
            ]
        }

… other series
 ]
};
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.serieslist = data.records;
```

**HTML**

```
    <div ng-repeat="series in serieslist">
        <ul ng-repeat="book in series.book">            
            <li>                  
                <div>{{series.name}}</div>
                <div>{{book.name}}</div>                    
            </li>            
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: How would you like the result?. ie

Comment: Please provide your desired HTML structure (non-nested). If I understood you correctly, you will need to use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` in order to have a *flat* HTML structure. But cannot write a concrete answer without your new HTML structure.

Comment: how about this`<div ng-repeat="series in serieslist">
            <li>                  
                <div>{{series.name}}</div>
                <div>{{series.book[0].name}}</div>
            </li>            
        </ul>
    </div>`

Comment: Here is what I expected <ul><li>book1 of series1</li><li>book 2 of series 1</li><li>book1 of series 2</li><li>book2 of series 2</li><li>book1 of series 3</li><li>book2 of series 3</li></ul>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Controller**

```
$scope.serieslist = data.records;
    $scope.flatbooklist = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.serieslist, function (series)
    {
        angular.forEach(series.book, function (book)
        {
            $scope.flatbooklist.push({seriesname: series.name, seriesid: series.seriesid, bookname: book.name, bookid: book.bookid, bookimage: book.image});
        });
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<ul ng-repeat="book in flatbooklist">
    <li>
        <div>{{book.seriesname}}</div>
        <div>{{book.bookname}}</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want only one list of books, try this

```
<div ng-repeat="series in serieslist">
        <li>                  
            <div>{{series.name}}</div>
            <div>{{series.book[0].name}}</div>
        </li>            
    </ul>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have just tried it and it only display the series name and the name of the first book of each series

Answer (score 1):

You need to flatten the array first in your controller into an array with series number and book number, and then use the ng-repeat on the new array.

To do that you can use two angular.forEach on the original array (one for the series and other for the books in each series).

```
$scope.serieslist = [];
    var seriesNumber = 1;
    angular.forEach(data.records, function(series) {
        var bookNumber = 1;
        angular.forEach(series.book, function(book) {
            $scope.serieslist.push(
                {
                    seriesNumber: seriesNumber,
                    bookNumber: bookNumber++,
                    seriesid: series.seriesid,
                    name: series.name,
                    book: book
                });
        });
        seriesNumber++;
    });
```

Here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/JoNAGu5AqXxQrV6tnYPx?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. It work flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

[Working JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tL602cz8/2/)

Just replace element of DOM for use nested `ng-repeat`

```
<div ng-app='Your app'>
     <div ng-controller='Your controlelr'>
        <ul ng-repeat="series in serieslist">            
            {{series.name}} 
            <li ng-repeat="book in series.book" >{{ book.name }}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
 </div>
```

or

```
 <div ng-app='myApp'>
     <div ng-controller='Home'>
        <ul ng-repeat="series in serieslist">            
            <li ng-repeat="book in series.book" >{{ book.name }} of {{series.name}}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
 </div>
```

[for this result](https://jsfiddle.net/tL602cz8/3/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This looks like my current approach. My question is how to do it with only 1 ng-repeat because nested ng-repeat will generates multiple lists which makes it very difficult to implement line wrap

Comment: Maybe with angular.foreach in controller but it's not possible for me with one ng-repeat, you need to loop in any case because there are two arrays

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like underscorejs to produce a flattened version of your list and then ng-repeat over that. For how you might do that, refer to Karl's answer on this stackoverflow question here: [How to flatten with ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076168/how-to-flatten-with-ng-repeat)

Comment: I very appreciate your answer. This is what I wanted. I used forEach of Angular instead of for loop and it works.